# Getting href in a html line

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to get information from an html datasheet. Particularly, I am trying to get the href = ... in the following line:

```
<a class="block" href="/post/BpkL7ColOVj" style="background-image: url(https://scontent-ort2-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/09e1b7436c9125092433c041c35c1eaa/5BDB064D/t51.2885-15/e15/s480x480/43913877_2130106893692252_5245480330715053223_n.jpg)">
```

```
soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'block'})
```

Is there any other way using BeautifulSoup to get what is contained in the href?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `['attribute_name']` this will get attributes by their name.

```
soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'block'})[0]['href']
>>> '/post/BpkL7ColOVj'
```

You can also use `css selector` which I think is more straightforward:

```
soup.select('a.block')[0]['href'] # same thing.
```